# Graceful shutdown of Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, shutdown, etcd

We have a 4 node Kubernetes cluster, installed using Juju 2.0 and the official canonical Kubernetes charm. The sole purpose of this very local and private installation is development and testing.

One of the biggest and documented issues of this install is complete lack of a graceful server shutdown procedure. As only as `etcd` nodes go down, the whole config is lost.

We have spent a considerable amount of time looking for an automated backup / restore script  / procedures for Kubernetes. The most frequent answer to the problem we have is to deploy the server from a scratch using Juju whenever we boot it. Given 30-35min. deployment time it doesn't seem like an attractive solution?

Do you happen to have any feasible solution to this problem?

Comment: I have asked the developers of the **kubernetes-core** charm for **juju 2.0** about graceful shutdown routines. The **graceful shutdown** feature is currently under development. You can track the progress here: https://github.com/juju-solutions/bundle-kubernetes-core/issues/37

Answer (score 1):

what about backing up the etcd config to restore on start up?

https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/v2/admin_guide.html

Doesn't that save you quite some time?